# Can I use Scrapy for scraping and parsing only?

Tags: python, database, parsing, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I've searched around, but can't seem to find any answers specifically for what I want to do. I'd like to scrape content from a pre-defined list of webpages (my growing list of bookmarks) and submit relevant content to a MySQL database for later search indexing. I don't need to crawl other pages beyond this list.

I'm assuming that Scrapy won't store the entire webpage in the database, but only the relevant parts needed for effective indexing. On the [offical scrapy website](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html), it lists 9 steps involved in the Web crawling process. For what I want to do, I only need to go through steps 4 - 8 once and send the results to my database using an item pipeline.

Is it possible to use Python code to call only the appropriate functions from Scrapy, in order to carry out steps 4 - 8 in this manner? I'm new to both Scrapy and Python, so your advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Given you do not return new requests, scrapy will not download additional content.

Comment: OK, thanks. Got it.